# How to prove that this series diverges: $ 3-\frac{9}{2}+\frac{27}{4}-\frac{81}{8}+\frac{243}{16}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, geometric-series

I would like to now, how to prove that this series diverges.

$$
3-\frac{9}{2}+\frac{27}{4}-\frac{81}{8}+\frac{243}{16}...    
$$

How could I prove it?
I have tried the n-term criterion that requires to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ is not zero, but I don't know how to express $a_n$.

exist another method?

Comment: Hint: Geometric series and common ratios.

Comment: Check the sums $n_2 + n_3$, $n_4 + n_5,$ $\dots$.

Comment: The $n$-th term seems to be $3 \cdot (-3/2)^n$,so you have a classic geometric series. Since $|-3/2|>1$, the series is divergent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expres the series how follows

$$
3-\frac{9}{2}+\frac{27}{4}-\frac{81}{8}+\frac{243}{16}... = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{3^n}{2^{n-1}}    
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{3^n}{2^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -1(-1)^{n} \frac{3^n}{2^{-1}2^{n}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{2^{-1}}(-1)^{n} \frac{3^n}{2^{n}}
$$
agrouping the equal powers it gives:

$$
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -2 \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n
$$

Then, this is a geometric series and diverges by the ratio convergence criterion $|-3/2| >1$